# What is the best way to start C# for a C, COBOL programmer?

Tags: c#

I know C,C++,COBOL.

Now I am trying to learn C# and I want to do some hobby projects with C#.

So can you suggest where do I start from.

I searched on google but I want to start from a book which gives me more practice problems for a new comer to .net

Can anybody suggest a great book online which I should really start from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have referred several books and this book is great.

You may download it from [Professional C#, Third Edition](http://www.flazx.com/ebook1039.php)

This is also a good book. Didn't read the whole book but i had a look few months back

[Sams Teach youe self C# in 24 hours](http://www.flazx.com/ebook10401.php)

Comment: +1 for Professional C#, Third Edition, best C# book

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to start with basic video tutorials first you can find more than source for videos like [this](http://www.learncsharp.com).

Then after you finish the basic features and main differences you can go in depth 
by reading more detailed books like [CLR via C#](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/Books/6522.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Everyone learns a little differently, so I've included a few different types of resources.

### Books

It seems that one of the biggest challenges for a COBOL programmer to move to a language like C# is the Object-Oriented way everything is done.  "Everything is an object" is a pretty good generalization within C#, and certainly good enough for a beginner.  So, the first suggestion is a book about [Object Thinking](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619654).  It attempts to introduce objects for a philosophical and historical perspective.  It specifically discusses some of the differences between procedural languages and OO languages. Now, it is a bit academic (written by a professor) but there's a good fundamental basis here.

Once OO is understood, there are a number of C# books available.  Many people recommend Richter's [CLR via C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735627045) which is a spectacularly good book.  If the person is a veteran to CS, you can't recommend a better, more thorough book on C# and the CLR.  For a more "approachable", feature-oriented way, I've always found [Troelsen](http://www.amazon.com/Pro-2010-NET-Platform-Fifth) to be excellent.

### Websites

Another approach is to compare and contrast syntaxes.  Someone fluent in COBOL will think in COBOL when first attempting to write C#.  So here is an article on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/net-languages/COBOLvsVBvsCSharp.aspx)  that does a side-by-side comparison of VB.NET, C#, and COBOL.  It's not a complete overview, but it could be a good reference for someone trying to figure out how to, let's say, write a loop in C#.  There is also this [blog post](http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/11/converting-c-to-cobol/) which is more to the effect of taking C# and converting to COBOL.  Still, the comparison between the two may be helpful.

### Training

For those that need instructor-led courses, Microsoft offers [Getting Started with Microsoft .NET for COBOL Programmers](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/course.aspx?ID=2363A&locale=en-us).  Exactly where this would be offered, however, may be a challenge.

### Coding

Fujistu makes a cool product called [NetCOBOL for .NET](http://www.netcobol.com/).  Nothing beats writing code.  Here, you can write COBOL code within Visual Studio to produce Microsoft's Intermediate Language (MSIL) which runs on the CLR (how cool).  Using this, a COBOL programmer could write OO COBOL, but leverage the .NET Framework.  Perhaps using this, you could go the next step and use [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) to decompile the IL into C#, VB, etc.  The web-site doesn't list a price which means "If you have to ask, you can't afford it."  Also, the goal here ISN'T to write more COBOL, so this may be a highly-addictive crutch to make the transition to C#.

### Videos

Fujistu also has published a series of .NET for COBOL programmers on youtube.  The intro video is located [here](http://www.youtube.com/user/fujitsucobol#p/u/40/jJuVp5uUClA) and the first lesson is [here](http://www.youtube.com/user/fujitsucobol#p/u/38/3Ot_pY30DG0), but anything by the user [fujistucobol](http://www.youtube.com/user/fujitsucobol) would be good.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in building a few hobby projects then it may be worthwhile just starting by downloading and installing a free Express version of Visual Studio and working through the samples and quickstarts.

Nothing like a bit of coding to get up to speed.

Answer (score 0):

From a C/C++ background a rapid coverage of C#'s syntax should be sufficient (it isn't that much different), especially given C++'s OO.

I would suggest "[C# in a Nutshell](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596527570/)" (O'Reilly) for a rapid coverage of the language.

Then start coding.

Your real challenge is the scope of the framework, I would suggest starting with simple console applications to get the very basics, and then expand into one of WinForms, Web Service & Client, or ASP.NET. Note web apps (ASP.NET) will require also HTML and CSS (and maybe JavaScript) so maybe worth leaving to a second iteration of learning.